# Export PATH issue in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, path, gradle, osx-yosemite

I want to install gradle in my local mac machine and I'm using Yosemite OS. I try export GRADLE_HOME in .bash_profile, .profile, .bashrc, .zshrc files, but gradle -version command not working. there was no problem with Mac OSX Maverick. in which file must I write export commands. Thx!

EDIT:

```
GRADLE_HOME=~/Development/gradle
export PATH="$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Please always provide the exact error message. Also note that setting `GRADLE_HOME` isn't necessary or sufficient for being able to run the `gradle` command. The main thing required is to put `$GRADLE_HOME/bin` on your `PATH` (whether you hardcode `GRADLE_HOME` or not).

Comment: what shell are you using?  If you don't know, type in "`echo $SHELL`" at the Terminal command prompt.

Comment: I'm using zsh shell, my export strings in EDITED

Comment: change shell to bash try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36220914/1802348) answer